# Mysql Stored Procedure Select Column into OUT parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, out-parameters

I have a stored procedure similar to this one, and when I try to save it, I get this error:

> Undeclared variable: my_column

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p (OUT column_param VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN
    SELECT my_column INTO coumn_param limit 1;
END;
```

Why can I not select a column to return?

**Here my actual query within the procedure:**

```
select latitude into lat, longitude into lon
from cities cc
inner join countries c on cc.country_id = c.country_id
inner join regions r on cc.region_id = r.region_id and c.country_id = r.country_id
left join locations l on cc.city_id = l.city_id
where 
city = coalesce(cty, city) and
country = coalesce(ctry, country) and
region = coalesce(reg, region)
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your  syntax of `INTO` clause is incorrect

Assuming that your query itself is correct and functional and you have `lat` and `lon` variables declared change this part

```sql
select latitude into lat, longitude into lon
```

to

```sql
SELECT latitude, longitude INTO  lat, lon
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/18965)** demo

Comment: I can't do that with prepared statements can I?

Comment: @RyanNaddy If you mean with `PREPARE ... FROM ...` and `EXECUTE ... USING` then yes you can but you need to use user/session variables (`e.g. @lat`) instead of local variables that goes without `@`.

Comment: Okay I did this (as prepared stmt): `SELECT latitude, longitude INTO @lat, @lon .... ` then this (as normal): `select @lat, @lon into lat, lon;`